# Добавить класс при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. У меня есть такой список и мне нужно что бы при загрузке страницы к первой кнопке с классом .tablinks добавился класс .active. Это как я понимаю нужно через js делать, я в нем не разбираюсь поэтому прошу помощи

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks">Шутеры</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Гонки</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Симуляторы</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Приключения</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Спортивные</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Детские</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Хорроры</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем JS?

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks active">Шутеры</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Гонки</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Симуляторы</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Приключения</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Спортивные</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Детские</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Хорроры</button>
</div>
```

---

Но если так надо,то:

```js
document.querySelector('.tablinks:first-child').classList.add('active');
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks">Шутеры</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Гонки</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Симуляторы</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Приключения</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Спортивные</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Детские</button>
      <button class="tablinks">Хорроры</button>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!